# Lisp Product Function

Tags: function, common-lisp, multiplication

I'm just starting out on lisp. I'm trying to make a product function written in Lisp. The function should take in an arbitrary parameter x, and returns the product of all numerical values contained in x. It should produce the following:

```
>(product 'x) -> 1
>(product '(x 5)) -> 5
>(product '((2 2)3)) -> 12 
>(product '((a 3)(2 1))) -> 6
```

I was able to do the following:

```
(defun product (x)
    "This function takes in an arbitrary parameter x, and returns the product of all numeric values contained within x."
    (cond
        ((consp x) (* (car x)(product (cadr x))))
        ((numberp x) x)
        (t 1)
    )
)
```

This handles the cases like

```
(product '(2 5))-> 10
(product 'x) -> 1
```

But not for ones like:

```
>(product '(x 5)) -> 5
>(product '((2 2)3)) -> 12
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first clause of your `cond` expression reads as follows:

> If x is a cons cell, multiply its first element (assumed to be a number) with the result of calling `product` on its second element (or NIL).

Both `(product '(x 5))` and `(product '((2 2) 3))` fail because the first element is not a number. You should multiply by `(product (car x))` instead of `(car x)`, in order to convert your arbitrary terms into numbers.

Note also that recursing on `cadr` is not enough to iterate over all elements of your input list. You probably intended to use `cdr`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I'll try adding the changes you suggested.